# Image and text showing above the fixed header when scrolling down

Tags: html, css

I am new to HTML and CSS
I tried to create an eCommerce based page.
my header is fixed but when I scroll down the page the image overflow on it.
if my method to create site is odd or strange then please guide me or mention me to adopt new way to do it.
screenshot is here

[image: screenshot]

Here is the my code attached in the post.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#header {
  width: 100%;
  height: 60px;
  background-color: #090;
  position: fixed;
}

#wrapper {
  width: 80%;
  background-color: #F7F4F4;
  margin: auto;
}

#main1 {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #FF6;
}

#main1::after {
  content: " ";
  display: block;
  clear: both;
}

#leftside {
  width: 20%;
  height: 300px;
  background-color: #0FF;
  float: left;
}

#middle {
  width: 60%;
  height: 300px;
  background-color: #00F;
  float: left;
  color: white;
}

#rightside {
  width: 20%;
  height: 300px;
  background-color: #636;
  float: right;
}

#special_discount {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #FF6;
}

#special_discount::after {
  content: " ";
  display: block;
  clear: both;
}

#sp_dis_leftside {
  width: 20%;
  height: 300px;
  background-color: #0FF;
  float: left;
}

#sp_dis_middle {
  width: 60%;
  height: 300px;
  background-color: #00F;
  float: left;
  color: white;
}

#sp_dis_rightside {
  width: 20%;
  height: 300px;
  background-color: #636;
  float: right;
}

#newsletter {
  background: #C1282B;
  width: 100%;
  height: 80px;
}

#recommended {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #FF6;
}

#recommended::after {
  content: " ";
  display: block;
  clear: both;
}

#recom_leftside {
  width: 20%;
  height: 300px;
  background-color: #0FF;
  float: left;
}

#recom_rightside {
  width: 80%;
  height: 300px;
  background-color: #636;
  float: right;
  color: white;
}

#ads1 {
  background: #C1282B;
  width: 100%;
  height: 80px;
  color: white;
}

#category1 {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #FF6;
}

#category1::after {
  content: " ";
  display: block;
  clear: both;
}

#cat1_leftside {
  width: 20%;
  height: 350px;
  background-color: #0FF;
  float: left;
}

#cat1_rightside {
  width: 80%;
  height: 350px;
  background-color: #636;
  float: right;
  color: white;
}

#home_category1_boxes1 {
  width: 180px;
  position: absolute;
  display: inline;
  height: 350px;
}

#home_category1_boxes2 {
  width: 390px;
  position: absolute;
  display: inline;
  height: 350px;
  margin-left: 200px;
}

#home_category1_boxes3 {
  width: 390px;
  position: absolute;
  display: inline;
  height: 350px;
  margin-left: 577px;
}

#ads_worldwide {
  background: #C1282B;
  width: 100%;
  height: 80px;
  color: white;
}

#category2 {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #FF6;
}

#category2::after {
  content: " ";
  display: block;
  clear: both;
}

#cat2_leftside {
  width: 20%;
  height: 300px;
  background-color: #0FF;
  float: left;
}

#cat2_rightside {
  width: 80%;
  height: 300px;
  background-color: #636;
  float: right;
  color: white;
}

#ads2 {
  background: #C1282B;
  width: 100%;
  height: 80px;
  color: white;
}

#category3 {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #FF6;
}

#category3::after {
  content: " ";
  display: block;
  clear: both;
}

#cat3_leftside {
  width: 20%;
  height: 300px;
  background-color: #0FF;
  float: left;
}

#cat3_rightside {
  width: 80%;
  height: 300px;
  background-color: #636;
  float: right;
  color: white;
}

#category4 {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #FF6;
}

#category4::after {
  content: " ";
  display: block;
  clear: both;
}

#cat4_leftside {
  width: 20%;
  height: 300px;
  background-color: #0FF;
  float: left;
}

#cat4_rightside {
  width: 80%;
  height: 300px;
  background-color: #636;
  float: right;
  color: white;
}

#ads3 {
  background: #C1282B;
  width: 100%;
  height: 80px;
  color: white;
}

#category5 {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #FF6;
}

#category5::after {
  content: " ";
  display: block;
  clear: both;
}

#cat5_leftside {
  width: 20%;
  height: 300px;
  background-color: #0FF;
  float: left;
}

#cat5_rightside {
  width: 80%;
  height: 300px;
  background-color: #636;
  float: right;
  color: white;
}

#category6 {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #FF6;
}

#category6::after {
  content: " ";
  display: block;
  clear: both;
}

#cat6_leftside {
  width: 20%;
  height: 300px;
  background-color: #0FF;
  float: left;
}

#cat6_rightside {
  width: 80%;
  height: 300px;
  background-color: #636;
  float: right;
  color: white;
}

#ads4 {
  background: #C1282B;
  width: 100%;
  height: 80px;
  color: white;
}

#category7 {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #FF6;
}

#category7::after {
  content: " ";
  display: block;
  clear: both;
}

#cat7_leftside {
  width: 20%;
  height: 300px;
  background-color: #0FF;
  float: left;
}

#cat7_rightside {
  width: 80%;
  height: 300px;
  background-color: #636;
  float: right;
  color: white;
}

#category8 {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #FF6;
}

#category8::after {
  content: " ";
  display: block;
  clear: both;
}

#cat8_leftside {
  width: 20%;
  height: 300px;
  background-color: #0FF;
  float: left;
}

#cat8_rightside {
  width: 80%;
  height: 300px;
  background-color: #636;
  float: right;
  color: white;
}

#ads5 {
  background: #C1282B;
  width: 100%;
  height: 80px;
  color: white;
}

#category9 {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #FF6;
}

#category9::after {
  content: " ";
  display: block;
  clear: both;
}

#cat9_leftside {
  width: 20%;
  height: 300px;
  background-color: #0FF;
  float: left;
}

#cat9_rightside {
  width: 80%;
  height: 300px;
  background-color: #636;
  float: right;
  color: white;
}

#category10 {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #FF6;
}

#category10::after {
  content: " ";
  display: block;
  clear: both;
}

#cat10_leftside {
  width: 20%;
  height: 300px;
  background-color: #0FF;
  float: left;
}

#cat10_rightside {
  width: 80%;
  height: 300px;
  background-color: #636;
  float: right;
  color: white;
}

#footer {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: #2F2F2F;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
  <title>Resposive layout</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
</head>

<body>
  <div id="header">
    <h3> Header area </h3>

  </div>

  <div id="wrapper">


    <div id="main1">
      <div id="leftside">
        <h3> Categories </h3>
      </div>
      <div id="middle">
        <h3> Slider </h3>
      </div>
      <div id="rightside">
        <h3> Mobile App </h3>
      </div>
    </div>

    <br>

    <div id="special_discount">
      <div id="sp_dis_leftside">
        <h3> Mega Discount box </h3>
      </div>
      <div id="sp_dis_middle">
        <h3> Top Brands </h3>
      </div>
      <div id="sp_dis_rightside">
        <h3> Crazy Discount </h3>
      </div>
    </div>

    <br>
    <div id="newsletter">
      <h3>Subscribe to Newsletter</h3>
    </div>
    <br>

    <div id="recommended">
      <div id="recom_leftside">
        <h3> Best for You </h3>
      </div>
      <div id="recom_rightside">
        <h3> Recommended Products Manual Slider </h3>
      </div>
    </div>

    <br>
    <div id="ads1">
      <h3>Single Product Ads to Buy</h3>
    </div>
    <br>

    <div id="category1">
      <div id="cat1_leftside">
        <h3> Horizontal Slider Cat 1 </h3>
      </div>

      <div id="cat1_rightside">
        <h3> </h3>
      </div>
      <div id="home_category1_boxes1">
        <ol>
          <h3>Men Dress</h3>
        </ol>
        <ol>Men Dress 1</ol>
        <ol>Men Dress 2</ol>
        <ol>Men Dress 3</ol>
        <br>
        <ol>
          <h3>Men Accessories</h3>
        </ol>
        <ol>Men Accessories1</ol>
        <ol>Men Accessories2</ol>
        <ol>Men Accessories3</ol>

      </div>
      <div id="home_category1_boxes2"> <img src="images/boxes/cat1/big.jpg" width="376" height="350"></div>
      <div id="home_category1_boxes3">
        <img src="images/boxes/cat1/box1.jpg" width="140px" />
        <img src="images/boxes/cat1/box2.jpg" width="140px" />
        <img src="images/boxes/cat1/box3.jpg" width="140px" />
        <img src="images/boxes/cat1/box4.jpg" width="140px" />
      </div>
    </div>

    <br>
    <div id="ads_worldwide">
      <h3>Shopping Worldwide</h3>
    </div>
    <br>

    <div id="category2">
      <div id="cat2_leftside">
        <h3> Horizontal Slider Cat 2 </h3>
      </div>
      <div id="cat2_rightside">
        <h3> Category 2 Top Brans with 1 big pic and 4 box pics </h3>
      </div>
    </div>

    <br>
    <div id="ads2">
      <h3>Single Product Ads to Buy</h3>
    </div>
    <br>

    <div id="category3">
      <div id="cat3_leftside">
        <h3> Horizontal Slider Cat 3 </h3>
      </div>
      <div id="cat3_rightside">
        <h3> Category 3 Top Brans with 1 big pic and 4 box pics </h3>
      </div>
    </div>

    <br>

    <div id="category4">
      <div id="cat4_leftside">
        <h3> Horizontal Slider Cat 4 </h3>
      </div>
      <div id="cat4_rightside">
        <h3> Category 4 Top Brans with 1 big pic and 4 box pics </h3>
      </div>
    </div>

    <br>
    <div id="ads3">
      <h3>Single Product Ads to Buy</h3>
    </div>
    <br>

    <div id="category5">
      <div id="cat5_leftside">
        <h3> Horizontal Slider Cat 5 </h3>
      </div>
      <div id="cat5_rightside">
        <h3> Category 5 Top Brans with 1 big pic and 4 box pics </h3>
      </div>
    </div>

    <br>

    <div id="category6">
      <div id="cat6_leftside">
        <h3> Horizontal Slider Cat 6 </h3>
      </div>
      <div id="cat6_rightside">
        <h3> Category 6 Top Brans with 1 big pic and 4 box pics </h3>
      </div>
    </div>

    <br>
    <div id="ads4">
      <h3>Single Product Ads to Buy</h3>
    </div>
    <br>

    <div id="category7">
      <div id="cat7_leftside">
        <h3> Horizontal Slider Cat 7 </h3>
      </div>
      <div id="cat7_rightside">
        <h3> Category 7 Top Brans with 1 big pic and 4 box pics </h3>
      </div>
    </div>

    <br>

    <div id="category8">
      <div id="cat8_leftside">
        <h3> Horizontal Slider Cat 8 </h3>
      </div>
      <div id="cat8_rightside">
        <h3> Category 8 Top Brans with 1 big pic and 4 box pics </h3>
      </div>
    </div>

    <br>
    <div id="ads5">
      <h3>Single Product Ads to Buy</h3>
    </div>
    <br>

    <div id="category9">
      <div id="cat9_leftside">
        <h3> Horizontal Slider Cat 9 </h3>
      </div>
      <div id="cat9_rightside">
        <h3> Category 9 Top Brans with 1 big pic and 4 box pics </h3>
      </div>
    </div>

    <br>

    <div id="category10">
      <div id="cat10_leftside">
        <h3> Horizontal Slider Cat 10 </h3>
      </div>
      <div id="cat10_rightside">
        <h3> Category 10 Top Brans with 1 big pic and 4 box pics </h3>
      </div>
    </div>

    <br>
    <div id="footer">

    </div>

  </div>


</body>

</html>
```

Comment: You can look into the answer that I provided. It will surely help you...

Comment: yes it does help too .... no doubt you are good at it. canu take a loot at here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43028173/responsive-layout-for-mobile-tablet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not managing the order of the elements in your page and that's why you are facing an issue like this. You need to apply a [z-index](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2009/09/the-z-index-css-property-a-comprehensive-look/) property on the  header to avoid this problem.

For example: `z-index: 100;`

```
#header {
  width: 100%;
  height: 60px;
  background-color: #090;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 100; // add it here and set it to a reasonable value
}
```

---

In an HTML page, the natural stacking order (i.e. the order of elements on the Z axis) is determined by a number of factors. Below is a list showing the order that items fit into a stacking context, starting with the bottom of the stack. This list assumes none of the items has z-index applied:

- Background and borders of the element that establish stacking context
- Elements with negative stacking contexts, in order of appearance
- Non-positioned, non-floated, block-level elements, in order of appearance
- Non-positioned, floated elements, in order of appearance
- Inline elements, in order of appearance
- Positioned elements, in order of appearance

The z-index property, when applied correctly, can change this natural stacking order. Of course, the stacking order of elements is not evident unless elements are positioned to overlap one another.

#### Your working code is below...

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#header {
  width: 100%;
  height: 60px;
  background-color: #090;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 100;
}

#wrapper {
  width: 80%;
  background-color: #F7F4F4;
  margin: auto;
}

#main1 {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #FF6;
}

#main1::after {
  content: " ";
  display: block;
  clear: both;
}

#leftside {
  width: 20%;
  height: 300px;
  background-color: #0FF;
  float: left;
}

#middle {
  width: 60%;
  height: 300px;
  background-color: #00F;
  float: left;
  color: white;
}

#rightside {
  width: 20%;
  height: 300px;
  background-color: #636;
  float: right;
}

#special_discount {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #FF6;
}

#special_discount::after {
  content: " ";
  display: block;
  clear: both;
}

#sp_dis_leftside {
  width: 20%;
  height: 300px;
  background-color: #0FF;
  float: left;
}

#sp_dis_middle {
  width: 60%;
  height: 300px;
  background-color: #00F;
  float: left;
  color: white;
}

#sp_dis_rightside {
  width: 20%;
  height: 300px;
  background-color: #636;
  float: right;
}

#newsletter {
  background: #C1282B;
  width: 100%;
  height: 80px;
}

#recommended {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #FF6;
}

#recommended::after {
  content: " ";
  display: block;
  clear: both;
}

#recom_leftside {
  width: 20%;
  height: 300px;
  background-color: #0FF;
  float: left;
}

#recom_rightside {
  width: 80%;
  height: 300px;
  background-color: #636;
  float: right;
  color: white;
}

#ads1 {
  background: #C1282B;
  width: 100%;
  height: 80px;
  color: white;
}

#category1 {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #FF6;
}

#category1::after {
  content: " ";
  display: block;
  clear: both;
}

#cat1_leftside {
  width: 20%;
  height: 350px;
  background-color: #0FF;
  float: left;
}

#cat1_rightside {
  width: 80%;
  height: 350px;
  background-color: #636;
  float: right;
  color: white;
}

#home_category1_boxes1 {
  width: 180px;
  position: absolute;
  display: inline;
  height: 350px;
}

#home_category1_boxes2 {
  width: 390px;
  position: absolute;
  display: inline;
  height: 350px;
  margin-left: 200px;
}

#home_category1_boxes3 {
  width: 390px;
  position: absolute;
  display: inline;
  height: 350px;
  margin-left: 577px;
}

#ads_worldwide {
  background: #C1282B;
  width: 100%;
  height: 80px;
  color: white;
}

#category2 {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #FF6;
}

#category2::after {
  content: " ";
  display: block;
  clear: both;
}

#cat2_leftside {
  width: 20%;
  height: 300px;
  background-color: #0FF;
  float: left;
}

#cat2_rightside {
  width: 80%;
  height: 300px;
  background-color: #636;
  float: right;
  color: white;
}

#ads2 {
  background: #C1282B;
  width: 100%;
  height: 80px;
  color: white;
}

#category3 {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #FF6;
}

#category3::after {
  content: " ";
  display: block;
  clear: both;
}

#cat3_leftside {
  width: 20%;
  height: 300px;
  background-color: #0FF;
  float: left;
}

#cat3_rightside {
  width: 80%;
  height: 300px;
  background-color: #636;
  float: right;
  color: white;
}

#category4 {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #FF6;
}

#category4::after {
  content: " ";
  display: block;
  clear: both;
}

#cat4_leftside {
  width: 20%;
  height: 300px;
  background-color: #0FF;
  float: left;
}

#cat4_rightside {
  width: 80%;
  height: 300px;
  background-color: #636;
  float: right;
  color: white;
}

#ads3 {
  background: #C1282B;
  width: 100%;
  height: 80px;
  color: white;
}

#category5 {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #FF6;
}

#category5::after {
  content: " ";
  display: block;
  clear: both;
}

#cat5_leftside {
  width: 20%;
  height: 300px;
  background-color: #0FF;
  float: left;
}

#cat5_rightside {
  width: 80%;
  height: 300px;
  background-color: #636;
  float: right;
  color: white;
}

#category6 {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #FF6;
}

#category6::after {
  content: " ";
  display: block;
  clear: both;
}

#cat6_leftside {
  width: 20%;
  height: 300px;
  background-color: #0FF;
  float: left;
}

#cat6_rightside {
  width: 80%;
  height: 300px;
  background-color: #636;
  float: right;
  color: white;
}

#ads4 {
  background: #C1282B;
  width: 100%;
  height: 80px;
  color: white;
}

#category7 {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #FF6;
}

#category7::after {
  content: " ";
  display: block;
  clear: both;
}

#cat7_leftside {
  width: 20%;
  height: 300px;
  background-color: #0FF;
  float: left;
}

#cat7_rightside {
  width: 80%;
  height: 300px;
  background-color: #636;
  float: right;
  color: white;
}

#category8 {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #FF6;
}

#category8::after {
  content: " ";
  display: block;
  clear: both;
}

#cat8_leftside {
  width: 20%;
  height: 300px;
  background-color: #0FF;
  float: left;
}

#cat8_rightside {
  width: 80%;
  height: 300px;
  background-color: #636;
  float: right;
  color: white;
}

#ads5 {
  background: #C1282B;
  width: 100%;
  height: 80px;
  color: white;
}

#category9 {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #FF6;
}

#category9::after {
  content: " ";
  display: block;
  clear: both;
}

#cat9_leftside {
  width: 20%;
  height: 300px;
  background-color: #0FF;
  float: left;
}

#cat9_rightside {
  width: 80%;
  height: 300px;
  background-color: #636;
  float: right;
  color: white;
}

#category10 {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #FF6;
}

#category10::after {
  content: " ";
  display: block;
  clear: both;
}

#cat10_leftside {
  width: 20%;
  height: 300px;
  background-color: #0FF;
  float: left;
}

#cat10_rightside {
  width: 80%;
  height: 300px;
  background-color: #636;
  float: right;
  color: white;
}

#footer {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: #2F2F2F;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
  <title>Resposive layout</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
</head>

<body>
  <div id="header">
    <h3> Header area </h3>

  </div>

  <div id="wrapper">


    <div id="main1">
      <div id="leftside">
        <h3> Categories </h3>
      </div>
      <div id="middle">
        <h3> Slider </h3>
      </div>
      <div id="rightside">
        <h3> Mobile App </h3>
      </div>
    </div>

    <br>

    <div id="special_discount">
      <div id="sp_dis_leftside">
        <h3> Mega Discount box </h3>
      </div>
      <div id="sp_dis_middle">
        <h3> Top Brands </h3>
      </div>
      <div id="sp_dis_rightside">
        <h3> Crazy Discount </h3>
      </div>
    </div>

    <br>
    <div id="newsletter">
      <h3>Subscribe to Newsletter</h3>
    </div>
    <br>

    <div id="recommended">
      <div id="recom_leftside">
        <h3> Best for You </h3>
      </div>
      <div id="recom_rightside">
        <h3> Recommended Products Manual Slider </h3>
      </div>
    </div>

    <br>
    <div id="ads1">
      <h3>Single Product Ads to Buy</h3>
    </div>
    <br>

    <div id="category1">
      <div id="cat1_leftside">
        <h3> Horizontal Slider Cat 1 </h3>
      </div>

      <div id="cat1_rightside">
        <h3> </h3>
      </div>
      <div id="home_category1_boxes1">
        <ol>
          <h3>Men Dress</h3>
        </ol>
        <ol>Men Dress 1</ol>
        <ol>Men Dress 2</ol>
        <ol>Men Dress 3</ol>
        <br>
        <ol>
          <h3>Men Accessories</h3>
        </ol>
        <ol>Men Accessories1</ol>
        <ol>Men Accessories2</ol>
        <ol>Men Accessories3</ol>

      </div>
      <div id="home_category1_boxes2"> <img src="images/boxes/cat1/big.jpg" width="376" height="350"></div>
      <div id="home_category1_boxes3">
        <img src="images/boxes/cat1/box1.jpg" width="140px" />
        <img src="images/boxes/cat1/box2.jpg" width="140px" />
        <img src="images/boxes/cat1/box3.jpg" width="140px" />
        <img src="images/boxes/cat1/box4.jpg" width="140px" />
      </div>
    </div>

    <br>
    <div id="ads_worldwide">
      <h3>Shopping Worldwide</h3>
    </div>
    <br>

    <div id="category2">
      <div id="cat2_leftside">
        <h3> Horizontal Slider Cat 2 </h3>
      </div>
      <div id="cat2_rightside">
        <h3> Category 2 Top Brans with 1 big pic and 4 box pics </h3>
      </div>
    </div>

    <br>
    <div id="ads2">
      <h3>Single Product Ads to Buy</h3>
    </div>
    <br>

    <div id="category3">
      <div id="cat3_leftside">
        <h3> Horizontal Slider Cat 3 </h3>
      </div>
      <div id="cat3_rightside">
        <h3> Category 3 Top Brans with 1 big pic and 4 box pics </h3>
      </div>
    </div>

    <br>

    <div id="category4">
      <div id="cat4_leftside">
        <h3> Horizontal Slider Cat 4 </h3>
      </div>
      <div id="cat4_rightside">
        <h3> Category 4 Top Brans with 1 big pic and 4 box pics </h3>
      </div>
    </div>

    <br>
    <div id="ads3">
      <h3>Single Product Ads to Buy</h3>
    </div>
    <br>

    <div id="category5">
      <div id="cat5_leftside">
        <h3> Horizontal Slider Cat 5 </h3>
      </div>
      <div id="cat5_rightside">
        <h3> Category 5 Top Brans with 1 big pic and 4 box pics </h3>
      </div>
    </div>

    <br>

    <div id="category6">
      <div id="cat6_leftside">
        <h3> Horizontal Slider Cat 6 </h3>
      </div>
      <div id="cat6_rightside">
        <h3> Category 6 Top Brans with 1 big pic and 4 box pics </h3>
      </div>
    </div>

    <br>
    <div id="ads4">
      <h3>Single Product Ads to Buy</h3>
    </div>
    <br>

    <div id="category7">
      <div id="cat7_leftside">
        <h3> Horizontal Slider Cat 7 </h3>
      </div>
      <div id="cat7_rightside">
        <h3> Category 7 Top Brans with 1 big pic and 4 box pics </h3>
      </div>
    </div>

    <br>

    <div id="category8">
      <div id="cat8_leftside">
        <h3> Horizontal Slider Cat 8 </h3>
      </div>
      <div id="cat8_rightside">
        <h3> Category 8 Top Brans with 1 big pic and 4 box pics </h3>
      </div>
    </div>

    <br>
    <div id="ads5">
      <h3>Single Product Ads to Buy</h3>
    </div>
    <br>

    <div id="category9">
      <div id="cat9_leftside">
        <h3> Horizontal Slider Cat 9 </h3>
      </div>
      <div id="cat9_rightside">
        <h3> Category 9 Top Brans with 1 big pic and 4 box pics </h3>
      </div>
    </div>

    <br>

    <div id="category10">
      <div id="cat10_leftside">
        <h3> Horizontal Slider Cat 10 </h3>
      </div>
      <div id="cat10_rightside">
        <h3> Category 10 Top Brans with 1 big pic and 4 box pics </h3>
      </div>
    </div>

    <br>
    <div id="footer">

    </div>

  </div>


</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Modify #header to add the following property:

```
z-index: 99 !important;
```

Try this,

```
#header {
width: 100%;
height: 60px;
background-color: #090;
position: fixed;
z-index: 99 !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `z-index` to specify the relative z-order (how high they sit in the stack) of elements. For more information see https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/z-index

In your example, setting the `z-index` of `#header` to `2` will achieve what you want, here's your code with just that added:

```css
*{margin:0; padding:0;}

#header{
 width:100%; height:60px; background-color:#090; position:fixed;
  z-index:2;
  }
#wrapper{
 width:80%; background-color:#F7F4F4; margin:auto;
  }
#main1{
 width:100%; background-color:#FF6; 
 }
#main1::after{content:" "; display:block; clear:both;
 }
#leftside{
 width:20%; height:300px; background-color:#0FF; float:left; 
 }
#middle{
 width:60%; height:300px; background-color:#00F; float:left; color: white; 
 }
#rightside{
 width:20%; height:300px; background-color:#636; float:right; 
 }



#special_discount{
 width:100%; background-color:#FF6;
 }
#special_discount::after{content:" "; display:block; clear:both;
 }
#sp_dis_leftside{
 width:20%; height:300px; background-color:#0FF; float:left;
 }
#sp_dis_middle{
 width:60%; height:300px; background-color:#00F; float:left; color: white;
 }
#sp_dis_rightside{
 width:20%; height:300px; background-color:#636; float:right;
 }



#newsletter{
 background: #C1282B; width: 100%; height: 80px;
 }

#recommended{
 width:100%; background-color:#FF6;
 }
#recommended::after{content:" "; display:block; clear:both;
 }
#recom_leftside{
 width:20%; height:300px; background-color:#0FF; float:left;
 }

#recom_rightside{
 width:80%; height:300px; background-color:#636; float:right; color: white;
 }

#ads1{
 background: #C1282B; width: 100%; height: 80px; color: white;
 }

#category1{
 width:100%; background-color:#FF6;
 }
#category1::after{content:" "; display:block; clear:both;
 }
#cat1_leftside{
 width:20%; height:350px; background-color:#0FF; float:left; 
 }

#cat1_rightside{
 width:80%; height:350px; background-color:#636; float:right; color: white; 
 }
#home_category1_boxes1{
 width: 180px; position: absolute; display: inline; height: 350px;
}
#home_category1_boxes2{
 width: 390px; position: absolute; display: inline; height: 350px; margin-left: 200px; 
}
#home_category1_boxes3{
 width: 390px; position: absolute; display: inline; height: 350px; margin-left: 577px; 
 
 
}
#ads_worldwide{
 background: #C1282B; width: 100%; height: 80px; color: white;
 }

#category2{
 width:100%; background-color:#FF6;
 }
#category2::after{content:" "; display:block; clear:both;
 }
#cat2_leftside{
 width:20%; height:300px; background-color:#0FF; float:left; 
 }

#cat2_rightside{
 width:80%; height:300px; background-color:#636; float:right; color: white;
 }

#ads2{
 background: #C1282B; width: 100%; height: 80px; color: white;
 }

#category3{
 width:100%; background-color:#FF6;
 }
#category3::after{content:" "; display:block; clear:both;
 }
#cat3_leftside{
 width:20%; height:300px; background-color:#0FF; float:left; 
 }

#cat3_rightside{
 width:80%; height:300px; background-color:#636; float:right; color: white;
 }

#category4{
 width:100%; background-color:#FF6;
 }
#category4::after{content:" "; display:block; clear:both;
 }
#cat4_leftside{
 width:20%; height:300px; background-color:#0FF; float:left; 
 }

#cat4_rightside{
 width:80%; height:300px; background-color:#636; float:right; color: white;
 }

#ads3{
 background: #C1282B; width: 100%; height: 80px; color: white;
 }

#category5{
 width:100%; background-color:#FF6;
 }
#category5::after{content:" "; display:block; clear:both;
 }
#cat5_leftside{
 width:20%; height:300px; background-color:#0FF; float:left; 
 }

#cat5_rightside{
 width:80%; height:300px; background-color:#636; float:right; color: white;
 }

#category6{
 width:100%; background-color:#FF6;
 }
#category6::after{content:" "; display:block; clear:both;
 }
#cat6_leftside{
 width:20%; height:300px; background-color:#0FF; float:left; 
 }

#cat6_rightside{
 width:80%; height:300px; background-color:#636; float:right; color: white;
 }

#ads4{
 background: #C1282B; width: 100%; height: 80px; color: white;
 }

#category7{
 width:100%; background-color:#FF6;
 }
#category7::after{content:" "; display:block; clear:both;
 }
#cat7_leftside{
 width:20%; height:300px; background-color:#0FF; float:left; 
 }

#cat7_rightside{
 width:80%; height:300px; background-color:#636; float:right; color: white;
 }

#category8{
 width:100%; background-color:#FF6;
 }
#category8::after{content:" "; display:block; clear:both;
 }
#cat8_leftside{
 width:20%; height:300px; background-color:#0FF; float:left; 
 }

#cat8_rightside{
 width:80%; height:300px; background-color:#636; float:right; color: white;
 }

#ads5{
 background: #C1282B; width: 100%; height: 80px; color: white;
 }

#category9{
 width:100%; background-color:#FF6;
 }
#category9::after{content:" "; display:block; clear:both;
 }
#cat9_leftside{
 width:20%; height:300px; background-color:#0FF; float:left; 
 }

#cat9_rightside{
 width:80%; height:300px; background-color:#636; float:right; color: white;
 }

#category10{
 width:100%; background-color:#FF6;
 }
#category10::after{content:" "; display:block; clear:both;
 }
#cat10_leftside{
 width:20%; height:300px; background-color:#0FF; float:left; 
 }

#cat10_rightside{
 width:80%; height:300px; background-color:#636; float:right; color: white;
 }
#footer{
 width:100%; height:100px; background-color:#2F2F2F;
 }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Resposive layout</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css"/>
</head>

<body>
<div id="header"> <h3> Header area </h3>   
    
    </div>
 
<div id="wrapper">

    
    <div id="main1">
     <div id="leftside"><h3> Categories </h3></div>
        <div id="middle"><h3> Slider </h3></div>
        <div id="rightside"><h3> Mobile App </h3></div>
    </div>
    
 <br>
   
    <div id="special_discount">
     <div id="sp_dis_leftside"><h3> Mega Discount box </h3></div>
        <div id="sp_dis_middle"><h3> Top Brands </h3></div>
        <div id="sp_dis_rightside"><h3> Crazy Discount </h3></div>
    </div>
    
    <br>
 <div id="newsletter"><h3>Subscribe to Newsletter</h3></div>
    <br>
    
   <div id="recommended">
     <div id="recom_leftside"><h3> Best for You </h3></div>        
        <div id="recom_rightside"><h3> Recommended Products Manual Slider </h3></div>
    </div>
    
    <br>
 <div id="ads1"><h3>Single Product Ads to Buy</h3></div>
    <br>
    
    <div id="category1">
      <div id="cat1_leftside"><h3> Horizontal Slider Cat 1 </h3></div>
  
      <div id="cat1_rightside"><h3>  </h3></div>
      <div id="home_category1_boxes1">
   <ol><h3>Men Dress</h3> </ol>
       <ol>Men Dress 1</ol>
       <ol>Men Dress 2</ol>
       <ol>Men Dress 3</ol>
       <br>
   <ol><h3>Men Accessories</h3></ol>
       <ol>Men Accessories1</ol>
       <ol>Men Accessories2</ol>
       <ol>Men Accessories3</ol>
                
        </div>
        <div id="home_category1_boxes2"> <img src="images/boxes/cat1/big.jpg" width="376" height="350"></div>
      <div id="home_category1_boxes3">
        <img src="images/boxes/cat1/box1.jpg" width="140px"/>
        <img src="images/boxes/cat1/box2.jpg" width="140px"/>
        <img src="images/boxes/cat1/box3.jpg" width="140px"/>
        <img src="images/boxes/cat1/box4.jpg" width="140px"/>
  </div>
    </div>
    
    <br>
 <div id="ads_worldwide"><h3>Shopping Worldwide</h3></div>
    <br>
    
     <div id="category2">
     <div id="cat2_leftside"><h3> Horizontal Slider Cat 2 </h3></div>        
        <div id="cat2_rightside"><h3> Category 2 Top Brans with 1 big pic and 4 box pics </h3></div>
    </div>
    
    <br>
 <div id="ads2"><h3>Single Product Ads to Buy</h3></div>
    <br>
    
       <div id="category3">
     <div id="cat3_leftside"><h3> Horizontal Slider Cat 3 </h3></div>        
        <div id="cat3_rightside"><h3> Category 3 Top Brans with 1 big pic and 4 box pics </h3></div>
    </div>
    
    <br>
    
       <div id="category4">
     <div id="cat4_leftside"><h3> Horizontal Slider Cat 4 </h3></div>        
        <div id="cat4_rightside"><h3> Category 4 Top Brans with 1 big pic and 4 box pics </h3></div>
    </div>
    
    <br>
 <div id="ads3"><h3>Single Product Ads to Buy</h3></div>
    <br>
    
      <div id="category5">
     <div id="cat5_leftside"><h3> Horizontal Slider Cat 5 </h3></div>        
        <div id="cat5_rightside"><h3> Category 5 Top Brans with 1 big pic and 4 box pics </h3></div>
    </div>
    
    <br>
     
      <div id="category6">
     <div id="cat6_leftside"><h3> Horizontal Slider Cat 6 </h3></div>        
        <div id="cat6_rightside"><h3> Category 6 Top Brans with 1 big pic and 4 box pics </h3></div>
    </div>
    
    <br>
 <div id="ads4"><h3>Single Product Ads to Buy</h3></div>
    <br>
    
       <div id="category7">
     <div id="cat7_leftside"><h3> Horizontal Slider Cat 7 </h3></div>        
        <div id="cat7_rightside"><h3> Category 7 Top Brans with 1 big pic and 4 box pics </h3></div>
    </div>
    
    <br>
    
    <div id="category8">
     <div id="cat8_leftside"><h3> Horizontal Slider Cat 8 </h3></div>        
        <div id="cat8_rightside"><h3> Category 8 Top Brans with 1 big pic and 4 box pics </h3></div>
    </div>
    
     <br>
 <div id="ads5"><h3>Single Product Ads to Buy</h3></div>
    <br>
    
    <div id="category9">
     <div id="cat9_leftside"><h3> Horizontal Slider Cat 9 </h3></div>        
        <div id="cat9_rightside"><h3> Category 9 Top Brans with 1 big pic and 4 box pics </h3></div>
    </div>
    
    <br>
    
    <div id="category10">
     <div id="cat10_leftside"><h3> Horizontal Slider Cat 10 </h3></div>        
        <div id="cat10_rightside"><h3> Category 10 Top Brans with 1 big pic and 4 box pics </h3></div>
    </div>
    
    <br>
    <div id="footer">
    
    </div>
    
    </div>


</body>
</html>
```