# Responsive layout for mobile tablet

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, media-queries

I created an ecommerce page and added @media to make the page responsive.
but its not working fine can you please take a look where I am doing mistake
more over if my coding style is wrong then please correct . More over my images are not also responsive too..

Here is the code

```css
@media(min-width:1200px){
*{margin:0; padding:0;}
 
#header{
 width:100%; height:54px; background-color:#090; position:fixed; z-index:2;
  }
#wrapper{
 width:80%; background-color:#F7F4F4; margin:auto;
  }

#category1{
 width:100%; background-color:#FF6;
 }
#category1::after{content:" "; display:block; clear:both;
 }
#cat1_leftside{
 width:20%; height:350px; background-color:#0FF; float:left; 
 }

#cat1_rightside{
 width:80%; height:350px; background-color:#636; float:right; color: white; 
 }
#home_category1_boxes1{
 width: 180px; position: absolute; display: inline; height: 350px;
}
#home_category1_boxes2{
 width: 390px; position: absolute; display: inline; height: 350px; margin-left: 200px; 
}
#home_category1_boxes3{
 width: 390px; position: absolute; display: inline; height: 350px; margin-left: 577px; 
 
}

#footer{
 width:100%; height:100px; background-color:#2F2F2F;
 }
}


@media(min-width:768px) and (max-width:1199px){
 *{margin:0; padding:0;}
 
#header{
 width:100%; height:54px; background-color:#090; position:fixed; z-index:2;
  }
#wrapper{
 width:80%; background-color:#F7F4F4; margin:auto;
  }

#category1{
 width:100%; background-color:#FF6;
 }
#category1::after{content:" "; display:block; clear:both;
 }
#cat1_leftside{
 width:20%; height:350px; background-color:#0FF; float:left; 
 }

#cat1_rightside{
 width:80%; height:350px; background-color:#636; float:right; color: white; 
 }
#home_category1_boxes1{
 width: 180px; position: absolute; display: inline; height: 350px;
}
#home_category1_boxes2{
 width: 390px; position: absolute; display: inline; height: 350px; margin-left: 200px; 
}
#home_category1_boxes3{
 width: 390px; position: absolute; display: inline; height: 350px; margin-left: 577px; 
 
}

#footer{
 width:100%; height:100px; background-color:#2F2F2F;
 }
}
@media(min-width:100px) and (max-width:767px){
 *{margin:0; padding:0;}
 
#header{
 width:100%; height:54px; background-color:#090; position:fixed; z-index:2;
  }
#wrapper{
 width:80%; background-color:#F7F4F4; margin:auto;
  }

#category1{
 width:100%; background-color:#FF6;
 }
#category1::after{content:" "; display:block; clear:both;
 }
#cat1_leftside{
 width:20%; height:350px; background-color:#0FF; 
 }

#cat1_rightside{
 width:80%; height:350px; background-color:#636; color: white; 
 }
#home_category1_boxes1{
 width: 180px; position: absolute; height: 350px;
}
#home_category1_boxes2{
 width: 390px; position: absolute; height: 350px; margin-left: 200px; 
}
#home_category1_boxes3{
 width: 390px; position: absolute; height: 350px; margin-left: 577px; 
 
}

#footer{
 width:100%; height:100px; background-color:#2F2F2F;
 }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Resposive layout</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css"/>
</head>

<body>
<div id="header"> <h3> Header area </h3>   
    
    </div>
<br>
<br>
<br>



<div id="wrapper">

       
    <div id="category1">
      <div id="cat1_leftside"><h3> Horizontal Slider Cat 1 </h3></div>
  
      <div id="cat1_rightside"><h3>  </h3></div>
      <div id="home_category1_boxes1">
   <ol><h3>Men Dress</h3> </ol>
       <ol>Men Dress 1</ol>
       <ol>Men Dress 2</ol>
       <ol>Men Dress 3</ol>
       <br>
   <ol><h3>Men Accessories</h3></ol>
       <ol>Men Accessories1</ol>
       <ol>Men Accessories2</ol>
       <ol>Men Accessories3</ol>
                
        </div>
        <div id="home_category1_boxes2"> <img src="images/boxes/cat1/big.jpg" width="376" height="350"></div>
      <div id="home_category1_boxes3">
        <img src="images/boxes/cat1/box1.jpg" width="140px"/>
        <img src="images/boxes/cat1/box2.jpg" width="140px"/>
        <img src="images/boxes/cat1/box3.jpg" width="140px"/>
        <img src="images/boxes/cat1/box4.jpg" width="140px"/>
  </div>
    </div>
    
    <br>       
    <div id="footer">
    
    </div>
    
    </div>


</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

EDITED AFER EDIT OF QUESTION AND COMMENTS:

First a general remark (from my original answer):

The usual way is to first define general rules which apply to *all* sizes and then (below that) define rules in media queries which overwrite some of the general rules.

This can be done with a mobile-first approach (where the general rules apply to mobile sizes and are then partly overwritten by desktio rules) or with a desktop-first apporach (where the general rules are for desktop and some of them overwritten for mobile sizes). I would NOT create three completely different sets of rules - it's just too much...

---

Now about your code: There are a lot of things I would change, but I won't recreate the whole page for you, so here is just a remark and answer to your last comment:

In the CSS for mobile you have this rule:

```
#home_category1_boxes3{
  width: 390px; position: absolute; height: 350px; margin-left: 577px; 
}
```

This means that a 390px wide container is placed 577px from the left border of its container/window, i.e. its right border will be 967px from the left border of the container. But that's inside a ruleset which only applies to screens below 768px width, so it is pushed out of the container by 200px - this simply cannot work. So, first of all, change that margin setting.

Actually, you shouldn't use `position: absolute` on those `.home_category1_boxes` containers - it makes them overlap and not-responsive in this case. Just erase that and try to create a regular flow of containers and elements.

Comment: now I hv edited the code it was wrongly written in the last @media. I want all the divs goes to vertical  style  and in cat 1 div if the page open to mobile

Comment: ah - so now you have three completely independent sets of rules - is that what you want? And what doesn't work the way you want it to?

Comment: yes now 3 set of rules would be apply liek desktop , table and mobile. in mobile the layout structure goes out and images goes to horizontal too , images dont resizing according to screen size.

Comment: If I remove the position: absolute , it will out of the div or structure what I want....  take a look at image http://imgur.com/a/YZOsy   ... might b my coding is wrong for all these.